# Building MATLAB and R interfaces to Ross Quinlan's C5.0

Tags: r, machine-learning, matlab

I'm considering building MATLAB and R interfaces to [Ross Quinlan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross_Quinlan)'s [C5.0](http://rulequest.com/download.html) (for those not familiar with it, C5.0 is a decision tree algorithm and software package; an extension of [C4.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5)), and I am trying to get a sense of the components I would need to write.

The only documentation I found for C5.0 is [here](http://www.rulequest.com/see5-win.html), which is a tutorial for See5 (a Windows interface to C5.0?) . The [tar](http://rulequest.com/GPL/C50.tgz) file comes with a Makefile, but no Readme files or any additional documentation.

From what I read in the tutorial above, C5.0 uses an ASCII-based representation to handle inputs and outputs, and I am also considering building an interface that passes binary data directly between MATLAB or R and C5.0. Is C5.0's data representation used by any other machine-learning/classification software?

Has anybody tried building a MATLAB or an R interface to ID3, C4.5 or C5.0 before?

Thanks

Comment: Is this project going on? I tried to install the package C5.0 in R, but failed.

Comment: Did you ever made an implementation of C5 for Matlab? If you did, it would be extremely useful. I am looking at interfacing C5 with Matlab right now, but C5 seems a bit messy (cannot just pass text files to and from it since it uses difficult formatting).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That sounds like a great idea, especially as the page you link to shows that C5.0 is now under GPL.

I have some experience wrapping C/C++ software to R using [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html); I would be happy to help.

Comment: thanks a lot for offering to help. We have a couple of students in our lab who may look into this.  We'll let you know as soon as we figure things out :)

Answer (score 6):

Interfacing C/C++ code to MATLAB is pretty straightforward, all you have to do is create a MEX gateway function to handle the conversion of parameters and return parameters.  I have experience in making MEX files to do this sort of thing and would be happy to help.

Comment: that sounds great! Thanks for being willing to help. We have a couple of students in our lab and they might reach out to you if we need help.

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE:

Now on CRAN:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/C50/index.html

ORIGINAL:

We've been working on this for a bit now (starting with Cubist then working on C5.0).

If you'd like to contribute:

https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/rulebasedmodels/

was created recently and we should be checking the initial code in.

We've had access to the Cubist sources for a while now (but there was an explicit agreement not to link it to other sw) and been debating the different options for incorporating the code, but I thin

Answer (score 2):

The C5.0 (Linux) documentation is at http://rulequest.com/see5-unix.html